# Hierarchy Problem with presenting Viewcontrollers, can someone help me?

Tags: ios, view, scrollview, hierarchy

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]i want to programm an App with two ViewControllers

The first one performs a segue to the second VC.

The Second VC has a Scrollview with different Views.

I did everything with Autolayout not with code

When i run the Application i get always the error "whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" and can't scroll to the bottom. I tried to find some solutions but nothing helped.

Hope someone can help me with the problem.

my first VC runs a normal performSegue("identifier",sender )

my code for the second VC is

```
import UIKit

class FragenViewController: UIViewController {

    var fragen = [Question]()
    var highscore = 0
    var questionNumber = 0


    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var answerButton1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerButton2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerButton3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerButton4: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var forwardButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var currentQuestionLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }
    @IBAction func answerButton_Tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }


}
```

the rest is with Main Storyboard Drag and drop

The Code from the first VC is

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var highscoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       // Setup Layout
        startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemFill
        startButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        startButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 20)
        startButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
        startButton.tintColor = UIColor.systemBlue

        highscoreLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18)



    }

    @IBAction func start_Button(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "startGame", sender: sender)

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi -- welcome to StackOverflow -- generally you want to show some code with your question.  If my answer doesn't help, show us the init() of the 2nd VC and what you have in your `prepareFor(segue` if you have one.

Comment: Hey thanks for your fast answer, i did a standard performSegue(...), and made nothing with code yet just drag and drop in the Main Storyboard.

Comment: what code is in the init() of the 2nd VC

Comment: i have added no Code to the second VC yet or where do i find the init() of the Second VC sorry i am a starter

Comment: Show us the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: Did you make a class for the second VC at all?  What did you set the class to in the storyboard?

Comment: 2020-05-17 20:28:32.270268+0200 Tausend Fragen[21930:1559533] Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7f9dff044400> on <Tausend_Fragen.ViewController: 0x7f9dfb006560> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: You need different classes (usually) for each different VC in your storyboard.  Is ViewController used for both?

Comment: The second VC has the class ViewController

Comment: What does the first one have?

Comment: no i have two different ViewController Files

Comment: Show us some of the code for the 2nd presented VC.  Show us the member variables and init() if it has one -- edit the question -- don't add code in comments

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image.

Comment: We need the 2nd one--  Please copy the text of the code and paste it

Comment: this is all of my Code

Comment: Now it looks as if your segue might not be pointing to the right thing.  I would look carefully at the segue lines and make sure they are set up right

Comment: i tried everything but i can't scroll on iPhone 8 or small Sizes. I read something about to run the Code on ViewDidAppear not on viewDidLoad, but i don*t know how to load the Autolayout Code on viewDidAppear? when i perform the Segue, the View already is loading